# nginx stopped serving index publicly after installing php

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, amazon-web-services

Nginx was serving a index.html fine from `/var/www/test/html/` from within the server and also when I curl'd the ip and port like `some-ip:8889`. Then I installed php because I was going to try serving a php file. After this point I could not curl `some-ip:8889` and it was also serving a apache help file instead of the default nginx file when I went to `http://some-ip`. Here is the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test` file:

```
server {
    listen 8889;
    listen [::]:8889;

    root /var/www/test/html;
    index index.html;

    server_name test.com www.test.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Also I linked sites-available/test to sites-enabled/test. I am also using AWS ubuntu image for the server. Any ideas how I can serve the index again on port `8889`?

Comment: Are you sure that Nginx is running? Try using `nginx -t` to test the configuration. In your question you mention Apache and PHP, but you don't say how they relate to Nginx or port 8889.

Comment: I am pretty sure its up, `sudo systemctl status nginx` shows it is active. I also did `sudo nginx -t` and it shows `test is successful`. I can still curl the default page and test page on port `8889` from within the server. Apache did not exist until I installed php on ubuntu 18.04 as I thought I needed php installed to be able to server php apps via nginx?

Comment: Well, yes, you need PHP, but not Apache.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem was I didn't add the port to the security group. The next thing I needed to do to serve php files was install php-fpm then add to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test`:

```
server {
...
  location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I restart nginx and php-fpm and that allows php to be served by nginx.